# How to resolve cook errors in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: error-handling, build, unreal-engine5

I'm a beginner in Unreal Engine5, and I'm trying to package my first third-person game, but keep getting hit by an error that I can't figure out and cannot find any examples online to help me fix it.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the errors]

So far I've gone over all my blueprints and checked for any errors, deleted unused Levels and deleted my intermediate folder.

Comment: Images of text should be avoided, ref: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)